# maven - separate some resources into a jar with a different classifier

Tags: java, maven

I have a project that includes some Java APIs, some resource files, and some pre-built machine learning models that can be used by the Java APIs. The models are currently in `src/main/resources` and the classes load them via `Class.getResource`. The models are used in several unit tests that make sure the APIs work as expected.

This is all basically fine, except that the models are quite large, and some users of the APIs may not need the models at all. (They'd just need the Java classes and the other smaller resource files.) So I'd like to arrange a distribution where users could choose to include the model files or not.

At first I thought that maybe the models should be a separate Maven project of their own, but if I pulled them out, I'm not sure how the dependencies would work. The models project would have to depend on the primary project for the Java APIs, but the primary project would have to depend on the models project for its tests. So that seems circular.

Then I thought that maybe I should be trying to create a separate jar with a classifier so that, e.g. users that need only the APIs would write:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
    <version>0.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and users who wanted both the APIs and the models would write:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
    <version>0.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
    <version>0.5.0</version>
    <classifier>models</classifier>
</dependency>
```

But I'm not sure how to set things up so that when I run `mvn package` some resources get separated out into a jar with a different classifier. How can I do that?

(Ideally, this would all happen with just the basic `mvn package` and would not require futzing around with, say, different profiles, since I would *always* be packaging things the same way.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given these points...

- You want your API and pre-built models to be separately deliverable artifacts.
- Theoretically, users of your API could provide their own models.
- You test your API with the pre-built deliverable models.

I believe the problem is that you are using the deliverable models for unit testing.

I recommend you do the following:

- Create a separate maven module for the models as you were initially inclined to do. They would be in `src/main/resources` of the new module. Your API module would no longer have models in `src/main/resources`.
- In the API module, create some simpler models designed solely for unit testing and place them in `src/test/resources`. Make them as minimalist as possible to test the API functionality. Re-write your API unit tests to use those instead. As a starting point you could make a copy of the deliverable models and place them here, but I recommend a smaller set of test data that has examples of each kind of thing a model can contain.
- If you want to test you have correctly authored your pre-built models, have the new model module depend on the API module, and write unit tests for the pre-built models in the model module.

That leaves you with no module cycles, models separate from API, unit tests for the API, and optionally unit tests for the deliverable models.

Comment: Yeah, this could work. It does make me feel a bit uneasy though for a few reasons. First, the new project would have an empty src/main/java, which just seems a bit odd. Second, it would double the number of modules in a multi-module project that already has >10 modules. Third, it would double the number of steps to make a release, since I would always have to be releasing things in pairs.

Comment: To your points: 1) Maven is not for building just Java. Its reasonable to have no `src/main/java` at all and just have a `src/main/resources`. 2) From your example I don't see how it would double the number of modules, however, modules are for managing dependencies. If you need >10 its for a good reason, or maybe you have sliced things up to too fine a granularity (only you can know). 3) I guess it depends on what you mean by "release", but you can have any number of artifacts in a release. You can even wrap them up into a single artifact with the assembly plugin or similar.

Comment: 2) It would double the number of modules because for each current module foo:bar, there would now be another module foo:bar-models.
3) But to wrap them in a single artifact, I'd need yet another module, right?

Comment: 3) If you follow the "maven way", yes. Its ok to have many modules provided you define them to create cohesive units of software. The days of the giant non-modular software tree are largely gone. By the way, if you decide you want to do something via the classifier approach and figure out a way around the dependency issue, you are still creating the same number of artifacts, releasing the same number of them, etc. You will just have fewer Maven modules that hack the Maven convention.

Comment: By the way, I do suggest that unless you have a large code base, or one based on plugins, 5 modules of Java is somewhat suspect. If clients always will have all 5 on the classpath they probably should be one jar. Perhaps the case you have. Just mentioning since you want to avoid module proliferation.

Comment: No, they won't always have all modules on the classpath, they'd probably have between 2 and 10, depending on exactly what they were doing, and the 10 might be different for each client.